# Arduino interupt a delay function

Tags: loops, arduino, interrupt, led

in my next project i use 4 Leds with delay(10000). I need a function for cancel this loop and start again with a new delay value e.g. 100.

I have enabled interrupts and when i pressed a button, delay changed to 100 AFTER a round. I have to wait 10 seconds.. It is possible to restart the loop function with the new values?

Comment: Sometimes the answer is "No, and you messed up with the implementation. Try again, this time specifying the requirements."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that was rude ignacio
At least be helpful.

You can do this but not as you have implemented.

Delay is not good to be used in this circumstance. A much better way of implementing is to use a while loop like this:

```
int delayLED = 10000;

int beginMillis = millis();

while( millis() - beginMillis < delayLED)
{
    // insert the code for your "interrupt" here
    // kinda like this
    if(button pressed)
    {
        delayLED = 100;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is just a template not a complete answer.
Let me know if you have further questions.

Happy coding!

Comment: And I would add: look at the examples! The first tutorial always made with arduino is how to blink a LED with a delay, and the second without. Before trying to lose your time, try to learn how something works...

Comment: Not sure which example you are talking about but certainly the delay function itself on the arduino.cc website has a good write up on not using it for timing code. I think this is a perfectly valid question for someone new to Arduino. Whether they learn it in examples (?), in the documentation or by asking a question on a website like this.

Comment: I'm actually facing the same problem and I was wondering if there is not another way? What I don't like with this solution is that if the interruption is called after the flag variable evaluation, then the function will execute what we don't want to be executed. By the way it seems like a kind of pooling. Is there a way to actually unwind the stack of the function, or just to point to another adress memory when we are into the interrupt call? I want to be sure if it is actually possible, and If I could break my chip doing this?

Comment: No pooling. This evaluates constantly based on the current Millis(). I dont understand why you would think it would break your chip, this kind of evaluation is constantly happening anyway. The reason why it was written this way is because the OP wanted to interrupt the current timing and immediately start the new timing. This function does that by looping out each cycle so that if the new delay time has been passed it would evaluate immediately and start the new timing. What exactly are you trying to do?